# Interpretation of AutoKeras Trial Summary Output

Tags: python, keras, auto-keras

For the AutoKeras 1.0 example below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import autokeras as ak

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
clf = ak.ImageClassifier(max_trials=10) # It tries 10 different models.
clf.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=3)
```

After training, the output looks like:

```
Epoch 1/3
1500/1500 [==============================] - 254s 169ms/step - loss: 0.1751 - accuracy: 0.9463 - val_loss: 0.0634 - val_accuracy: 0.9818
Epoch 2/3
1500/1500 [==============================] - 259s 173ms/step - loss: 0.0779 - accuracy: 0.9756 - val_loss: 0.0534 - val_accuracy: 0.9843
Epoch 3/3
1500/1500 [==============================] - 220s 147ms/step - loss: 0.0624 - accuracy: 0.9800 - val_loss: 0.0470 - val_accuracy: 0.9872
[Trial complete]
[Trial summary]
 |-Trial ID: e2ba122017b8f0d6e3c8eed7c6c208ab
 |-Score: 0.04698652009871633
 |-Best step: 0
 > Hyperparameters:
 |-classification_head_1/dropout_rate: 0.5
 |-classification_head_1/spatial_reduction_1/reduction_type: flatten
 |-dense_block_1/dropout_rate: 0
 |-dense_block_1/num_layers: 1
 |-dense_block_1/units_0: 128
 |-dense_block_1/use_batchnorm: False
 |-image_block_1/augment: False
 |-image_block_1/block_type: vanilla
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/dropout_rate: 0.25
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/filters_0_0: 32
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/filters_0_1: 64
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/kernel_size: 3
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/max_pooling: True
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/num_blocks: 1
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/num_layers: 2
 |-image_block_1/conv_block_1/separable: False
 |-image_block_1/normalize: True
 |-optimizer: adam
```

What is the interpretation of the content below "Trial Summary"? What does the "Best Step" represent?